# Set position of span based on the position of Dynamic label tag

Tags: html, css

I have a div that looks like this

```
<div style="width:100px;">
<label>dynamic label name</label>
<span style="color:red;">*</span>
</div>
```

Here the label name can be dynamic and of different length , so even when the length of label is more and it goes to second line the span(*) should stay in first line. That is * must be in first line for any length of label.

Solution preferable in CSS

Comment: `label { float:left; width:calc(100% - 1em); }` if you always want the star to be at the very right of the parent container; replace width with max-width if you want it to follow directly after the text in case that text is shorter than even a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox might be an option

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
}

span {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;">
  <label>dynamic label name</label>
  <span style="color:red;">*</span>
</div>

<div style="width:100px;">
  <label>label name</label>
  <span style="color:red;">*</span>
</div>
```

or CSS-Grid

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;">
  <label>dynamic label name</label>
  <span style="color:red;">*</span>
</div>

<div style="width:100px;">
  <label>label name</label>
  <span style="color:red;">*</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting the position of span absolute and positioning the span using left and top values works too!

Comment: Yes, but it's less flexible and can lead to overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try floating the span to the right or left?

```
float: left;
```

Or you might what something like a badge. Checkout this link : [Bootstrap Badge](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/badge/)

Comment: Sorry, its has already float:right. I want it to stay in same position even when the text in the label changes.

Comment: Just move it _before_ the label then?

Answer (score 0):

Div with width:100px will have `position:relative` and `span`will be absolutely positioned with `top:0` and `right:0`

Answer (score 0):

Please try also to use

```
overflow: auto
```

maybe it can help,

Answer (score -1):

Just give a display: flex to div tag it will keep the span in same line even there label is of multiple line

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;">
<label>dynamic label name</label>
<span style="color:red;">*</span>
</div>
```